# Error when using a parameter for a period in AWS Data Pipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-data-pipeline

I tried to create a parametrised pipeline on AWS and old the parameters wok fine except the ones to be plugged on a period:

```
{
  "id": "DefScheduler",
  "type": "Schedule",
  "startDateTime": "2016-09-26T00:00:00",
  "period": "#{myPeriod}"
}
```

When I open the architect view on the AWS console, I see this error:

```
Object:DefScheduler
ERROR: 'period' value should be of the form: <number> [SECONDS|MINUTES|HOURS|DAYS|WEEKS|MONTHS]
```

The value is defined on a parameters json file as follows:

```
{
  "description": "How ofter do you want to run the job",
  "id": "myPeriod",
  "type": "String",
  "watermark":"1 HOURS",
  "default":"1 HOURS"
},
```

I tried to override it with a defined value, but no luck. Any ideas? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Can you try "hours"?

According to the docs the [period](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-expressions-functions.html#dp-datatype-period) is specified as follows:

> Period
>
> Indicates how often a scheduled event should run. It's expressed in
>   the format "N [years|months|weeks|days|hours|minutes]", where N is a
>   positive integer value.
>
> The minimum period is 15 minutes and the maximum period is 3 years.
>
> The following example sets the period field of the Schedule object to
>   3 hours. This creates a schedule that runs every three hours.
>
> "period" : "3 hours"

Comment: same issue, seems to be a problem with the editor not allowing parametrised periods, I can run the pipeline successfully if I don't enter the pipeline design GUI.

Answer (score 2):

If anyone stumbles across this - I had the same error when trying to parameterise terminateAfter in datapipeline.
The fix for me was to use Fn::Sub instead of passing in "1 Hours" directly.

```
            - Key: terminateAfter
              StringValue:
                Fn::Sub:
                  - "${Time} Hours"
                  - Time:
                      Ref: TerminateAfter
```

Answer (score 1):

The parameter Period should be of Type Period, but if you trait it as it receive an error.

```
 {
  "id": "myPeriod",
  "description": "N [years|months|weeks|days|hours|minutes] ",
  "type": "Period",
  "optional":"false"
}
```

Value for parameter attribute 'type' is not supported.

I tried also to traits as two different arguments but doesn't work.

```
 {
  "id": "myInterval",
  "description": "years|months|weeks|days|hours|minutes]",
  "type": "String",
  "optional":"false"
}


{
      "id": "myTimeUnit",
      "description": "N ",
      "type": "Integer",
      "optional":"false"
    }
```